# What is correct way to implement A* algorithm? Do we update nodes in closedSet or not?

Tags: algorithm, graph, a-star

As I in A* algorithm (A-star algorithm) we keep nodes in two lists: one priority queue and one regular array. The priority queue is called openSet, the other one is called closedSet.

'openSet' containts the nodes we are going to visit, closedSet are nodes we already visited.

Here's a pseudocode that implements A* algorithm:

```
openSet.add(startNode)
while not openSet.empty():
    currentNode = openSet.get()
  
    if currentNode == targetNode: # This is to stop searching when target is found
        break
    
    closedSet.add(currentNode)


    for neighborNode in currentNode.neighbors:
        if neighborNode not in openSet and not in closedSet:
            neighborNode.previousNode = currentNode   #building a path from currentNode to neighbor node
            neighborNode.g = currentNode.g + adjecentEdge.weight
            neighborNode.h = heuristic(neighborNode, targetNode)
            neighborNode.f = neighborNode.g + neighborNode.h
            openSet.add(neighborNode)
        else if neighborNode.g > currentNode.g + adjecentEdge.weight:
            neighborNode.previousNode = currentNode   #building a path from currentNode to neighbor node
            neighborNode.g = currentNode.g + adjecentEdge.weight
            neighborNode.h = heuristic(neighborNode, targetNode)
            neighborNode.f = neighborNode.g + neighborNode.h
                #Should I remove this part or not?
                if neighborNode in closedSet:
                    closedSet.remove(neighborNode)
                    openSet.add(neighborNode)


return getPath(startNode, targetNode)
```

In this code I do update nodes if it has less cost, I update whether it's a node in closedSet or not, and if it's a node in closedSet I remove that from closedSet and add it to openSet.

Do we update nodes in closedSet or not in A* algorithm?

I did implement both in Python, both does find the shortest path.

When I don't update nodes in closedSet it finds the path faster in my Graphs, but it may be just some coincidence.

Here's another pseudocode which doesn't update nodes in closedSet at all:

Here's a pseudocode that implements A* algorithm:

```
openSet.add(startNode)
while not openSet.empty():
    currentNode = openSet.get()
  
    if currentNode == targetNode: # This is to stop searching when target is found
        break
    
    closedSet.add(currentNode)


    for neighborNode in currentNode.neighbors:
        if neighborNode not in openSet and not in closedSet:
            neighborNode.previousNode = currentNode   #building a path from currentNode to neighbor node
            neighborNode.g = currentNode.g + adjecentEdge.weight
            neighborNode.h = heuristic(neighborNode, targetNode)
            neighborNode.f = neighborNode.g + neighborNode.h
            openSet.add(neighborNode)
        else if neighborNode not in closedSet and neighborNode.g > currentNode.g + adjecentEdge.weight:
            neighborNode.previousNode = currentNode   #building a path from currentNode to neighbor node
            neighborNode.g = currentNode.g + adjecentEdge.weight
            neighborNode.h = heuristic(neighborNode, targetNode)
            neighborNode.f = neighborNode.g + neighborNode.h

return getPath(startNode, targetNode)
```

When implementing A* algorithm do we update nodes in closedSet or not?

If we update nodes in closedSet, do we add them to openSet again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the heuristic is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic), the nodes in the closed set will not need to be updated.  If the heuristic is [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) but *not* consistent, the nodes in the closed set may need to be updated.

*Most* real-world heuristics are consistent, so most of the time that A* is implemented, that part of the algorithm is unnecessary and, for speed, not implemented at all.

Comment: Is Manhattan heuristics consistent?
If the weight of any edge (cost from one node to next node) is 0, then it could be that  ´h(N) > c(N,P)+h(P)´ (equation taken from the Wikipedia article you linked on consistent heuritics).
I tried both implementations where the code updates nodes in closedSet and where it does not do it.
When the A* code updates nodes in closedSet it takes more time to find targetNode, but the path it finds in some cases is a little more efficient than when A* code doesn't update nodes in closedSet.

Comment: @Coder88 Manhatten distance is mainly used in uniform grids, so there shouldn't ever be edges with weight 0. If your use-case has magic 0-cost portals, then no, manhattan distance will not be consistent.